Google update service (gupdate) missing in Services
I wanna update google chrome, and I got the error:

I tried to start the google update service (gupdate) in Services,  but it's not present.
How can I start it?


EDIT: Chrome is now running a current version, but the Google Update Service is still not present, and it is probable that my Chrome client will not update itself.
As expected chrome is not able to update, I got the same error.

Is this a company-owned computer, or do you own it yourself? I would try doing a repair install, to begin with, or uninstall/reinstall. Have you tried those yet?

I would download and reinstall the current version of Chrome.  This assumes you are an Administrator on the system. Chrome 118 was released in October 2023.  So your browser has been broken nearly an entire year.  You should make sure you don't have a LTS release installed.

Hello @music2myear it's my pc. Can I fix it without uninstalling chrome?

I updated chrome by running it as administrator. Now the only problem is that the google update service is still missing in Services.

Once you updated Chrome, is it updating itself OK now, just still missing this service? I ask because your comment says "the only problem is that...", but that was really the only problem you really clearly laid out in your question, so I'm not sure what problems installing Chrome might have resolved. Also, at this point it is probably a good idea to EDIT your post and update it with what you have done and the outcome. This will be very helpful info for others to understand this problem you are facing, and having it in the question is a good idea.

@music2myear I was thinking that I was unable to update chrome because the google update service was missing, but actually I updated it without this service, so now I think that it's a good thing to have also the service in order to avoid future problem in updating chrome.

Ok, so to summarize your current position: Chrome is now running a current version, but the Google Update Service is still not present, and it is probable that your Chrome client will not update itself. As I noted in my previous comment: Please update your question now, adding this information to it.

@music2myear thank you for the tip.
